# setTimeout not working client side on landing page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, settimeout

Good Afternoon, I am trying to have a loading animation for the pages on my site, but the client-side setTimeout function is not working. I have the same function on a test page with no bootstrap and no other scripts and it works, but once I put the script on my landing page it doesn't wait. I have console logged in setTimeout and it does log properly so it's firing, I just don't know why the page isn't waiting. I am using the EJS template engine.

```js
/* 1 */

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#loader").hide();
        }, 5000);
        $('#page').show();
    });
});





    /* 2. 
    Loading animation javascript */
    ! function (a, b) {
        "use strict";

        function c(a) {
            a = a || {};
            for (var b = 1; b < arguments.length; b++) {
                var c = arguments[b];
                if (c)
                    for (var d in c) c.hasOwnProperty(d) && ("object" == typeof c[d] ? deepExtend(a[d], c[d]) : a[d] = c[d])
            }
            return a
        }

        function d(d, g) {
            function h() {
                if (y) {
                    r = b.createElement("canvas"), r.className = "pg-canvas", r.style.display = "block", d.insertBefore(r, d.firstChild), s = r.getContext("2d"), i();
                    for (var c = Math.round(r.width * r.height / g.density), e = 0; c > e; e++) {
                        var f = new n;
                        f.setStackPos(e), z.push(f)
                    }
                    a.addEventListener("resize", function () {
                        k()
                    }, !1), b.addEventListener("mousemove", function (a) {
                        A = a.pageX, B = a.pageY
                    }, !1), D && !C && a.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function () {
                        F = Math.min(Math.max(-event.beta, -30), 30), E = Math.min(Math.max(-event.gamma, -30), 30)
                    }, !0), j(), q("onInit")
                }
            }

            function i() {
                r.width = d.offsetWidth, r.height = d.offsetHeight, s.fillStyle = g.dotColor, s.strokeStyle = g.lineColor, s.lineWidth = g.lineWidth
            }

            function j() {
                if (y) {
                    u = a.innerWidth, v = a.innerHeight, s.clearRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height);
                    for (var b = 0; b < z.length; b++) z[b].updatePosition();
                    for (var b = 0; b < z.length; b++) z[b].draw();
                    G || (t = requestAnimationFrame(j))
                }
            }

            function k() {
                i();
                for (var a = d.offsetWidth, b = d.offsetHeight, c = z.length - 1; c >= 0; c--)(z[c].position.x > a || z[c].position.y > b) && z.splice(c, 1);
                var e = Math.round(r.width * r.height / g.density);
                if (e > z.length)
                    for (; e > z.length;) {
                        var f = new n;
                        z.push(f)
                    } else e < z.length && z.splice(e);
                for (c = z.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) z[c].setStackPos(c)
            }

            function l() {
                G = !0
            }

            function m() {
                G = !1, j()
            }

            function n() {
                switch (this.stackPos, this.active = !0, this.layer = Math.ceil(3 * Math.random()), this.parallaxOffsetX = 0, this.parallaxOffsetY = 0, this.position = {
                    x: Math.ceil(Math.random() * r.width),
                    y: Math.ceil(Math.random() * r.height)
                }, this.speed = {}, g.directionX) {
                    case "left":
                        this.speed.x = +(-g.maxSpeedX + Math.random() * g.maxSpeedX - g.minSpeedX).toFixed(2);
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        this.speed.x = +(Math.random() * g.maxSpeedX + g.minSpeedX).toFixed(2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        this.speed.x = +(-g.maxSpeedX / 2 + Math.random() * g.maxSpeedX).toFixed(2), this.speed.x += this.speed.x > 0 ? g.minSpeedX : -g.minSpeedX
                }
                switch (g.directionY) {
                    case "up":
                        this.speed.y = +(-g.maxSpeedY + Math.random() * g.maxSpeedY - g.minSpeedY).toFixed(2);
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        this.speed.y = +(Math.random() * g.maxSpeedY + g.minSpeedY).toFixed(2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        this.speed.y = +(-g.maxSpeedY / 2 + Math.random() * g.maxSpeedY).toFixed(2), this.speed.x += this.speed.y > 0 ? g.minSpeedY : -g.minSpeedY
                }
            }

            function o(a, b) {
                return b ? void (g[a] = b) : g[a]
            }

            function p() {
                console.log("destroy"), r.parentNode.removeChild(r), q("onDestroy"), f && f(d).removeData("plugin_" + e)
            }

            function q(a) {
                void 0 !== g[a] && g[a].call(d)
            }
            var r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y = !!b.createElement("canvas").getContext,
                z = [],
                A = 0,
                B = 0,
                C = !navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|BB10|mobi|tablet|opera mini|nexus 7)/i),
                D = !!a.DeviceOrientationEvent,
                E = 0,
                F = 0,
                G = !1;
            return g = c({}, a[e].defaults, g), n.prototype.draw = function () {
                s.beginPath(), s.arc(this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY, g.particleRadius / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !0), s.closePath(), s.fill(), s.beginPath();
                for (var a = z.length - 1; a > this.stackPos; a--) {
                    var b = z[a],
                        c = this.position.x - b.position.x,
                        d = this.position.y - b.position.y,
                        e = Math.sqrt(c * c + d * d).toFixed(2);
                    e < g.proximity && (s.moveTo(this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY), g.curvedLines ? s.quadraticCurveTo(Math.max(b.position.x, b.position.x), Math.min(b.position.y, b.position.y), b.position.x + b.parallaxOffsetX, b.position.y + b.parallaxOffsetY) : s.lineTo(b.position.x + b.parallaxOffsetX, b.position.y + b.parallaxOffsetY))
                }
                s.stroke(), s.closePath()
            }, n.prototype.updatePosition = function () {
                if (g.parallax) {
                    if (D && !C) {
                        var a = (u - 0) / 60;
                        w = (E - -30) * a + 0;
                        var b = (v - 0) / 60;
                        x = (F - -30) * b + 0
                    } else w = A, x = B;
                    this.parallaxTargX = (w - u / 2) / (g.parallaxMultiplier * this.layer), this.parallaxOffsetX += (this.parallaxTargX - this.parallaxOffsetX) / 10, this.parallaxTargY = (x - v / 2) / (g.parallaxMultiplier * this.layer), this.parallaxOffsetY += (this.parallaxTargY - this.parallaxOffsetY) / 10
                }
                var c = d.offsetWidth,
                    e = d.offsetHeight;
                switch (g.directionX) {
                    case "left":
                        this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX < 0 && (this.position.x = c - this.parallaxOffsetX);
                        break;
                    case "right":
                        this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX > c && (this.position.x = 0 - this.parallaxOffsetX);
                        break;
                    default:
                        (this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX > c || this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX < 0) && (this.speed.x = -this.speed.x)
                }
                switch (g.directionY) {
                    case "up":
                        this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY < 0 && (this.position.y = e - this.parallaxOffsetY);
                        break;
                    case "down":
                        this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY > e && (this.position.y = 0 - this.parallaxOffsetY);
                        break;
                    default:
                        (this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY > e || this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY < 0) && (this.speed.y = -this.speed.y)
                }
                this.position.x += this.speed.x, this.position.y += this.speed.y
            }, n.prototype.setStackPos = function (a) {
                this.stackPos = a
            }, h(), {
                option: o,
                destroy: p,
                start: m,
                pause: l
            }
        }
        var e = "particleground",
            f = a.jQuery;
        a[e] = function (a, b) {
            return new d(a, b)
        }, a[e].defaults = {
            minSpeedX: .1,
            maxSpeedX: .7,
            minSpeedY: .1,
            maxSpeedY: .7,
            directionX: "center",
            directionY: "center",
            density: 1e4,
            dotColor: "#666666",
            lineColor: "#666666",
            particleRadius: 7,
            lineWidth: 1,
            curvedLines: !1,
            proximity: 100,
            parallax: !0,
            parallaxMultiplier: 5,
            onInit: function () { },
            onDestroy: function () { }
        }, f && (f.fn[e] = function (a) {
            if ("string" == typeof arguments[0]) {
                var b, c = arguments[0],
                    g = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                return this.each(function () {
                    f.data(this, "plugin_" + e) && "function" == typeof f.data(this, "plugin_" + e)[c] && (b = f.data(this, "plugin_" + e)[c].apply(this, g))
                }), void 0 !== b ? b : this
            }
            return "object" != typeof a && a ? void 0 : this.each(function () {
                f.data(this, "plugin_" + e) || f.data(this, "plugin_" + e, new d(this, a))
            })
        })
    }(window, document),
        /**
         * requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel
         * @see: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
         * @see: http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating
         * @license: MIT license
         */
        function () {
            for (var a = 0, b = ["ms", "moz", "webkit", "o"], c = 0; c < b.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++c) window.requestAnimationFrame = window[b[c] + "RequestAnimationFrame"], window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[b[c] + "CancelAnimationFrame"] || window[b[c] + "CancelRequestAnimationFrame"];
            window.requestAnimationFrame || (window.requestAnimationFrame = function (b) {
                var c = (new Date).getTime(),
                    d = Math.max(0, 16 - (c - a)),
                    e = window.setTimeout(function () {
                        b(c + d)
                    }, d);
                return a = c + d, e
            }), window.cancelAnimationFrame || (window.cancelAnimationFrame = function (a) {
                clearTimeout(a)
            })
        }();


    particleground(document.getElementById('particles-foreground'), {
        dotColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        lineColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)',
        minSpeedX: 0.3,
        maxSpeedX: 0.6,
        minSpeedY: 0.3,
        maxSpeedY: 0.6,
        density: 50000, // One particle every n pixels
        curvedLines: false,
        proximity: 250, // How close two dots need to be before they join
        parallaxMultiplier: 10, // Lower the number is more extreme parallax
        particleRadius: 4, // Dot size
    });

    particleground(document.getElementById('particles-background'), {
        dotColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        lineColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)',
        minSpeedX: 0.075,
        maxSpeedX: 0.15,
        minSpeedY: 0.075,
        maxSpeedY: 0.15,
        density: 30000, // One particle every n pixels
        curvedLines: false,
        proximity: 20, // How close two dots need to be before they join
        parallaxMultiplier: 20, // Lower the number is more extreme parallax
        particleRadius: 2, // Dot size
    });
```

```css
p {
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 0
}

p::before {
  content: "Placeholder for: "
}

#loader {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<p><%- include('layouts/head');  -%></p>
<p><%- include('layouts/index/index-style'); -%>  </p>
<p><%- include('layouts/index/google-analytics'); -%></p>

</head>

<body>
      <div id="loader">
        <div id="particles-background" class="vertical-centered-box"></div>
        <div id="particles-foreground" class="vertical-centered-box"></div>
      
        <div class="vertical-centered-box">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="loader-circle"></div>
            <div class="loader-line-mask">
              <div class="loader-line"></div>
            </div>
            <p><%- include('layouts/payment/paymentCanceled-svg'); -%></p>
      
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  <div id="page" class="container">  
       (page content is located within this container using bootstrap)

  
   
  </div>
  

      <p><%- include('layouts/footer');  -%></p>
      <p><%- include('layouts/scripts'); -%></p>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I edited your snippet slightly.  I made it runnable by adding jQuery, I added placeholder text for the EJS rendering so it doesn't look like it's broken, and changed the background to black so you can see that there are moving bits.  If you want to make it more like your actual content, then feel free to modify it further.  The takeaway from this is that it appears that your **5-second** timeout ***is*** working.  So I'm not sure what you think is wrong.

Comment: I wish I could show a video. The jquery script is inside the EJS scripts tag, I did take it out and add Jquery to the top of the document and it still did not work. The 5 second timeout is not working. When i load the page the animation just flashes quickly, its on the screen for less than a second.

Comment: I don't see that.  Did you click "Run code snippet" on the snippet in this question since I have edited it?  I see that your loader is displayed for 5 seconds then is hidden by `$("#loader").hide();`  I'm sorry but I'm having trouble reproducing what you are claiming to see.

Comment: I did run the code snippet and and it does work there, but not on my landing page. When i go to my landing page it doesnt wait 5 seconds for the timeout, the page just loads, and i am not sure why the page is just loading and not waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setTimeout was not the function I was looking for because my app was not waiting for the page to load. I instead used the below and it worked!

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
        document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
};
```